# R partial string matching and return value (in R)

Tags: r, string, match, return-value, product

I have multiple procurement databases on which I need to run a list of "keywords" that I have build to identify certain products and if there is match I would like to tag the products to a surgical category.

Here is an exemple.

Procurement database (in fact I have more than 2,000,000 line to go over):

```
d<-data.frame(prod_desc=c("BANDELETTE TVTO-OBTRYX HALO", "BANDELETTE MINI ARC PRECISES", "BANDELETTE D'ANALYSE POUR GLYCEMIE", "DIACH. BANDELETTE STER 19MM X 72MM","SLING MALE SYSTEM","DIACHILON","AIGUILLE","GANT","LABEL","CRAYON"),label=1:10)
```

List of keywords and return value (actual list much longer) :

```
kw<-data.frame(kw=c("bandelette","tvt","bande transvaginale","sling system","argus"),category="ss_bandelette")
```

I would like to find the products `prod_desc` that contains my keywords string `kw` and if there a match I would like to add a column in the `d` data frame that would return the `category` associated with the `kw` in the `kw` dataframe.

For now I was able to achieve the desired result using the following code :

```
d$match <- ifelse(d$cat <- grepl(paste(kw$kw,collapse="|"), d$name,ignore.case = TRUE) == "TRUE","SS_Bandelette","-")
```

But this code is not really efficient since I have about 350 keywords that are mapped to around 30 different categories. What code can I used to return the category automatically in the `d` dataframe if one of my keyword is triggered?

Thank you very much for your help.

Phil

Comment: @DarshanBaral I guess this question is different. even i thought the same earlier. I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# made all to lowercase
d$prod_desc <- tolower(d$prod_desc)
# create a logical matrix that specifies which keywords are present on each row of 'd'
m = data.frame(sapply(kw$kw, grepl, d$prod_desc))
colnames(m) = kw$kw

# create a column in 'd' with the corresponding keyword      
d$kw <- apply(m, 1, function(x) names(x)[which(x)[1]])
# simple merge
merge(d, kw, by = "kw", all.x = T)

#           kw                          prod_desc label      category
#1  bandelette bandelette d'analyse pour glycemie     3 ss_bandelette
#2  bandelette diach. bandelette ster 19mm x 72mm     4 ss_bandelette
#3  bandelette        bandelette tvto-obtryx halo     1 ss_bandelette
#4  bandelette       bandelette mini arc precises     2 ss_bandelette
#5        <NA>                  sling male system     5          <NA>
#6        <NA>                          diachilon     6          <NA>
#7        <NA>                           aiguille     7          <NA>
#8        <NA>                               gant     8          <NA>
#9        <NA>                              label     9          <NA>
#10       <NA>                             crayon    10          <NA>
```

Comment: @PhilippeLachapelle I am not sure if i got it right. Cold you test it on your real data and let me know

Comment: Joel, thank you very much. It works beautifully. Thank you for the quick answer. I will study your code now! Regards. PL

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create dataframe as per original question
d<-data.frame(prod_desc=c("BANDELETTE TVTO-OBTRYX HALO", "BANDELETTE MINI ARC PRECISES", "BANDELETTE D'ANALYSE POUR GLYCEMIE", "DIACH. BANDELETTE STER 19MM X 72MM","SLING MALE SYSTEM","DIACHILON","AIGUILLE","GANT","LABEL","CRAYON"),label=1:10)
# Create keywords as per origianl question
kw<-data.frame(kw=c("bandelette","tvt","bande transvaginale","sling system","argus"),category="ss_bandelette")
# Assume you want match/tag string on word boundaries? If not; "BANDELETTE TVTO-OBTRYX HALO" would match to "tvt" for instance.
kw$kw <- paste0("\\b",kw$kw,"\\b")

x <- sapply(kw$kw, function(x) grepl(tolower(x), tolower(d$prod_desc)))
d$Match <- apply(x, 1, function(i) paste0(names(i)[i]))
d$Match <- kw$category[match(d$Match,kw$kw)]
d
#                             prod_desc label         Match
# 1         BANDELETTE TVTO-OBTRYX HALO     1 ss_bandelette
# 2        BANDELETTE MINI ARC PRECISES     2 ss_bandelette
# 3  BANDELETTE D'ANALYSE POUR GLYCEMIE     3 ss_bandelette
# 4  DIACH. BANDELETTE STER 19MM X 72MM     4 ss_bandelette
# 5                   SLING MALE SYSTEM     5          <NA>
# 6                           DIACHILON     6          <NA>
# 7                            AIGUILLE     7          <NA>
# 8                                GANT     8          <NA>
# 9                               LABEL     9          <NA>
# 10                             CRAYON    10          <NA>
```