# Merge by partial string match in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, fuzzywuzzy

I've a df as under

```
+-------+---------+-------+
| Brand |  WORD   | Count |
+-------+---------+-------+
| ABC   | cell    |     1 |
| DEF   | dock    |     2 |
| XYZ   | surface |     3 |
| LMN   | pro     |     4 |
| ABC   | mobile  |     5 |
| DEF   | game    |     6 |
| XYZ   | mouse   |     7 |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

and another one:

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+
| Brand |      Name       | profit |
+-------+-----------------+--------+
| ABC   | cell game       |     10 |
| ABC   | cellular mobile |     20 |
| DEF   | docking station |     30 |
| XYZ   | surface mouse   |     40 |
| XYZ   | mouse device    |     50 |
| LMN   | pro device      |     60 |
+-------+-----------------+--------+
```

I want to merge them by partial string matching (word for word, meaning cell would match only with cell and not cellular) the WORD and name and grouped by the Brand, so the resulting table would be as under:

```
+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+
| Brand |     WORD      |      Name       | Count | profit |
+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+
| ABC   | cell          | cell game       |     1 |     10 |
| ABC   | mobile        | cellular mobile |     5 |     20 |
| XYZ   | surface mouse | surface mouse   |     3 |     40 |
| XYZ   | mouse         | mouse device    |     7 |     50 |
| XYZ   | mouse         | mouse device    |     7 |     50 |
| LMN   | pro           | pro device      |     4 |     60 |
+-------+---------------+-----------------+-------+--------+
```

I tried using the solution here
[R partial string matching and return value (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472132/r-partial-string-matching-and-return-value-in-r)

but it matches even parts of strings, like cell would be matched with cellular
was wondering if there was a way to have exact string match and get the results in the desired form

Comment: This will be tricky. You will have to define a whole bunch of new elements. For example, why won't surface mouse join with mouse device? Both contain the word mouse. I mean to the human brain we see why you want surface mouse to join with surface mouse, but I do not see why you dont want it to join with mouse device

Comment: Having been in a similar spot, my solution at the time was to first 'clean' the name column to remove off-target instances that could occur. In the off-target example you gave, could maybe do something like `df2$Name = gsub("cellular mobile", "mobile", df2$Name)`. Not perfect, but if you don't have a lot of off-target partial matches then that could work for you with a little data inspection.

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming here that you want to match the `Brand` columns and the `WORD` columnn to the `Name` column and that the output is to be ordered by `profit`. The output shown in the question has a duplicate row which we assume was an error.  The inputs `d1` and `d2` are shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

We pad `WORD` and `Name` with a space on either side to ensure that only word matches are used.  The `%` used in the `like` pattern is a wildcard that matches any string of 0 or more characters.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select d1.Brand, d2.Name, d1.WORD, d1.Count, d2.profit
  from d1
  join d2 on d1.Brand = d2.Brand and 
             ' ' || d2.Name || ' ' like '% ' || d1.WORD || ' %'
  order by d2.profit")
```

giving:

```
  Brand            Name    WORD Count profit
1   ABC       cell game    cell     1     10
2   ABC cellular mobile  mobile     5     20
3   XYZ   surface mouse surface     3     40
4   XYZ   surface mouse   mouse     7     40
5   XYZ    mouse device   mouse     7     50
6   LMN      pro device     pro     4     60
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form.

```
d1 <-
structure(list(Brand = c("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ", "LMN", "ABC", "DEF", 
"XYZ"), WORD = c("cell", "dock", "surface", "pro", "mobile", 
"game", "mouse"), Count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

d2 <-
structure(list(Brand = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"
), Name = c("cell game", "cellular mobile", "docking station", 
"surface mouse", "mouse device", "pro device"), profit = c(10, 
20, 30, 40, 50, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hi 
In your analysis d2 is actually the end result, it not the second dataframe that I'm matching against

Comment: OK. Have fixed it. Note that input is supposed to be shown in questions as the output of `dput(X)` where `X` is the input. See top of [tag:r] tag page  I have done it for you this time.